# Story where the main character learns to perceive time out of order from the aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, first-contact, quantum-physics

I read a story several years ago in which aliens come make first contact with Earth, and a bunch of scientists set to work trying to establish communication with them in various fields. The main character is a linguist and her team is working to try to figure out their written language, which doesn't have any sort of linear structure and can be read starting from any place.

It contains some explanation of quantum physics as an analogy for how they view time.

In the end, it turns out that the aliens don't perceive time in a linear fashion, and sort of see the future on equal terms with the past, etc. The main character learns to see time this way by studying their language, and the story is interspersed with her talking about what her child is going to do / is doing / has done.

I think I read it in a science fiction magazine but I'm not sure about this part.

Comment: http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/linguistics

Comment: Probably not it, but the "seeing the future on equal terms with the past" reminds me of [*Slaughterhouse-Five*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slaughterhouse-Five)

Comment: Was there a lot of frustration at the alien's attempts to describe their physics. And in the end it turned out that the FTL travel relied on them perceiving time as a tree?

Comment: @Richard I found what I was looking for in there, thanks! I'll write an answer about it.

Comment: Yes. That was the one I was thinking of; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_Your_Life - http://www.f.waseda.jp/sidoli/Chiang_Story_Of_Your_Life.pdf

Comment: (Is it acceptable to link to what is presumably a pirated copy in my answer?)

Comment: @porglezomp [It's not recommended](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1352/31051)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The story I was looking for was "Story of Your Life" by Ted Chiang. ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0048EKOP0), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_Your_Life), [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?84502)).

Thanks to Richard in the comments linking to the Science Fiction Encyclopedia entry on [linguistics](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/linguistics).

Comment: The SFE entry on [Time Out of Sequence](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/time_out_of_sequence) has a bit more on Chiang's story.

Comment: They're making a movie from it!

Comment: To echo @heltonbiker, it's called [Arrival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrival_(film)) (very original...) and it has been released already.